# How to not fill space in last row using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a requirement where I have a structure like below

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <!-- some 6 items here -->
  </div>
  <div class="content row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <!-- some 2 items here -->
  </div>
</div>


<style>
 .wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
</style>
```

Now the requirement is like [image]

I have tried using flex layout but it pushes the next row in new line. But the requirement to have them right after first row is finished.

Comment: Why haven't you used <br>

Comment: I want in same line, not in next line. br will push the content to new line. @coder9927

Comment: Alright make snse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:contents;` to make all them belong to the same upper container:

```css
.col-3 {
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.container > .content {
  display:contents;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="content row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <!-- some 6 items here -->
  </div>
  <div class="content row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <!-- some 2 items here -->
  </div>
</div>
```